# ParserError: Expected ',' but got '=>' --> token.sol:31:34: | 31 | require(balancesOf(from) => value, 'balance too low'); | ^^

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 100000000 *10 **18;
    string public name = "ECOT369";
    string public symbol = "ECO";
    uint public decimals = 18;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    
    function balancesOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balancesOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool){
        require(balancesOf(from) => value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] => value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public return(bool){
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats really not a question you should ask, you should be able  to figure it out by yourself ( just replace => with >=). Btw why isnt your contract using an internal _transfer function like the standard erc20/bep20 implementation?

Comment: Thank you! I am new to this! I fixed that problem and now I got another problem regarding SPDX.

Comment: Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information. --> token.sol

Comment: I don't know what standard erc20/bep20 is. I think I was watching the wrong tutorials.

Comment: It's almost like java but different

Comment: ok. Now It's compiled. Thank you! But I still dont know how to use internal transfer function

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol, thats the most standard way of implementing a token. Notice how the "transfer" and "transferFrom" functions both call an internal "_transfer" function that actually does the transfer. This avoids code repetition and makes the contract cheaper to deploy :)